# Sorting query in access returns incorrect result

Tags: ms-access

sorting in access Returns incorrect result

```
ID | Name
=======
1  | D
2  | D
3  | D
4  | A
5  | A
6  | C
7  | C
```

i need to sort by **ID** - but show only one **Name**.

```
ID | Name
=======
D
A
C
```

i try this:

```
select Distinct Name from MyTbl
```

Returns incorrect result

```
A
C
D
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved it !!

```
SELECT MyTbl.Name
FROM MyTbl
GROUP BY MyTbl.Name
ORDER BY Min(MyTbl.ID)
```